# What is the purpose of __table_args__ in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have no experience with sqlalchemy, and I have the following code:

```
class ForecastBedSetting(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'forecast_bed_settings'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('idx_forecast_bed_settings_forecast_id_property_id_beds',
              'forecast_id', 'property_id',
              'beds'),
    )

    forecast_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'forecasts.id'), nullable=False)
    property_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'properties.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    # more definition of columns
```

Although I have checked [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html), I cannot understand what is the purpose of `__table_args__`, so I have no clue what this line is doing:

```
__table_args__ = (
    Index('idx_forecast_bed_settings_forecast_id_property_id_beds',
    'forecast_id', 'property_id',
    'beds'),
)
```

Could somebody please explain me what is the purpose of `__table_args__`, and what the previous piece of code is doing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> This attribute accommodates both positional as well as keyword arguments that are normally sent to the `Table` constructor.

During construction of a declarative model class – `ForecastBedSetting` in your case – the metaclass that comes with `Base` [creates an instance of `Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html). The `__table_args__` attribute allows passing extra arguments to that `Table`. The created table is accessible through

```
ForecastBedSetting.__table__
```

The code [defines an index inline](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#indexes), passing the `Index` instance to the created `Table`. The index uses string names to identify columns, so without being passed to a table SQLAlchemy could not know what table it belongs to.

Comment: do you know how to add the __table_args__ to a many2many with the signature like country = Table(__tablename__, Column.......) that is not a class by definition?

Comment: @Tony `__table_args__` are arguments to a `Table` constructed by Declarative. If you construct a `Table` yourself, then you would just pass the arguments as usual.